# How to place quotes mark in ansible task with grep, awk, sed

Tags: awk, sed, grep, ansible, ps

My task search for config in CMD column to gather information what is directory of application config and also PID.

```
---
- hosts: all
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Check if process is running
      become: yes
      shell: 'ps -e --format="pid cmd" | grep process.cfg | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"| grep -v color'
      register: proces_out
```

output looks like this after this command:

```
32423 /var/local/bin/application -c /var/local/etc/process.cfg
```

But i think ansible have troubles with 2 greps in 1 command. I need them both because if i dont use reversed "grep -v color" this anoying thing appears "grep --color=auto ", i cant cut out PID that i need in another task which kills process because real process is in second line.

My second idea was to use AWK, which i think would be the best tool for this case, but if i use double quotation marks in --format parameter and in SED command and the single quotation mark in awk parameters they dont want to cooperate. Even if i keep them balanced they interfere with them selfs.

AWK idea:

```
shell: 'ps -e --format="pid cmd" | grep process.cfg | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"| awk 'FNR == 2''
```

I want to ask for a hint what would be the best to avoid incompatibility in code and be able to use it after as a output in variable

```
## PID
{{ proces_out.stdout.split(' ')[0] }} 
## application
{{ proces_out.stdout.split(' ')[1] }}
## config
{{ proces_out.stdout.split(' ')[3] }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i think ansible have troubles with 2 greps in 1 command

That is *for sure* not true

> if i dont use reversed "grep -v color" this anoying thing appears "grep --color=auto ", i cant cut out PID that i need in another task which kills process because real process is in second line.

You are running into the classic case of the grep process matching its own regex, as will happen in a lot of "simple" cases. What you want is a regex that matches your string but does not match itself. In that example above it would be:

```
  shell: 'ps -e --format="pid cmd" | grep process[.]cfg | sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"'
```

because `process[.]cfg` matches `process.cfg` but does not match `process[.]cfg` I also fixed your regex because in a regex, the `.` means any character, which doesn't appear to be what you really wanted to happen

With regard to that `--color` bit, you can likely can side-step that nonsense by using the full path to `grep`, which will cause bash to really execute the binary, versus some alias that uses `--color=auto`; I actually wouldn't have expected the colors to show up in an ansible run, because it's not the right `$TERM` but systems are weird

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Matthew for that solution, but i found diffirent option to avoid unnessesery output.
So syntax is almost the same, but i added to `--format` addonational parameter `ppid` Parent process id, in most case i belive parent process always have number 1 in output which helps to sort it as i want to.

It look like this:

```
  shell: >
    ps -e --format="ppid pid cmd" |
    grep process.cfg |
    sed -e "s/[[:space:]]\+/ /g"
  register: output_process
```

And output looks like this:

```
 1 54345 /var/local/bin/application -c /var/local/etc/process.cfg
6435 6577 grep --color=auto process.cfg
```

Now its easy we can use ansible modules to sort it:

```
- name: Kill process
  become: yes
  shell: "kill {{ output_process.stdout_lines[0].split(' ')[2] }}"
```

What it does? it selects line 0 which is first line, splits output between spaces and selects 3rd phrase. In output theres `:space:` before `ppid` thats why `PID` is 3rd

Thank you again for your solution Matthew, it might be helpfull in another case.